Reduce power consumption of 2011 21.5" iMac running Ubuntu Server
I installed Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS on a 2011 21.5" iMac to use as a Minecraft server within my LAN.
I want to reduce power consumption because there is no reason to waste power.
I tried to make the LCD turn off automatically using this guide.
The monitor turns black after the correct period of inactivity; however, the LCD backlight does not turn off.
The GPU creates alot of heat too.
Tuning power settings in powertop does not help much, if at all.
I would prefer to just unplug the monitor and the driver board completely.
(The LCD would still be in the computer for the purpose of airflow and protetion from high voltages)
However, when I unplug the monitor, the CPU fan goes up to full speed a minute after boot and stays at full speed forever, likely due to a lack of communiation with the temperature sensor.
How is the temperature sensor connected to the MotherBoard?
It is not a direct cable from sensor-> motherboard.
What should I do to turn off the LCD backlight and the GPU?

Apple does a lot of “unique” stuff with their hardware, so disconnecting things will not do much good. The simplest way to keep the display off is to use Ubuntu Desktop, which can run Minecraft Server just fine and has all the necessary bits to shut a display off after a certain amount of idle time.

@matigo Ubuntu server has no measurable background cpu usage or disk I/O.

@matigo Ubuntu Server is faster than Ubuntu desktop.
